# Handling/Pushing File Updates to User Browsers?

Tags: backbone.js, web-applications, single-page-application

When I make a change to my Backbone web application code on my server, how can I make user's browsers update so they see those changes.

Being a SPA the page rarely if ever refreshes. So even if place hashes/timestamps on my script tags it still wont be adequate enough, ie, this isn't ideal IMO:

```
...
<script src="js/main.js?t=SOME_HASH"></script>
```

Does Backbone have a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone being a JS framework that merely gives structure to your applications, it doesn't handle stuff like this. This is something that involves configuration of server and you need to tackle it yourself.

Since you said you have an SPA that rarely refreshes - Your app is probably contacting the server via lots of AJAX requests. You can add an interceptor to these requests on the server that checks if stuff changed on server and sends a `shouldReload: true` with the response.
You should also have an AJAX interceptor client side that checks for this in response and reloads the page/lets users know about updates on server and give option to reload/restart.

Another option is to implement websockets/polling so that server can push notification about changes to clients. [socket.io](https://socket.io/) is a plugin that uses web sockets and falls back to polling.

P.S: You also need to bust the cache as you mentioned in question